# Stop GoogleApiClient connecting after specific time

Tags: android, scheduler, google-api-client

Currently, I'm working with GoogleApiClient. And sometime, GoogleApiClient connecting and Game Snapshot openning have taken a long time because the slow network. So, I want to call disconnect it after specific time because I don't want user wait too long. Anyone has experience on it, could you give me some suggestions !

Thanks and best regards !

Comment: Use a CountDownTimer or any of the other lower level Java scheduling mechanisms to receive a signal when the time has ellapsed and, in your handler, call disconnect().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've the solution too long ago but forget this question. So, I come here again to answer my own question. Hope that help the orther people.

```
.await(YOUR_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
```

the full API [PendingResult.await](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/PendingResult.html#await(long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit))

```
void loadFromSnapshot(final SnapshotMetadata snapshotMetadata) {
        AsyncTask<Void, Void, Integer> task = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Integer>() {
            @Override
            protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {
                if (!isGoogleConnected()) {
                    return GamesStatusCodes.STATUS_NETWORK_ERROR_OPERATION_FAILED;
                }
                Snapshots.OpenSnapshotResult result;
                if (snapshotMetadata != null && snapshotMetadata.getUniqueName() != null) {
                    LogUtils.logD(TAG, "Opening snapshot by metadata: " + snapshotMetadata);
                    result = Games.Snapshots.open(mGoogleApiClient, snapshotMetadata).await();
                } else {
                    final boolean isDefaultMode = isDefaultMode();
                    LogUtils.logD(TAG, "Opening current save name " + (isDefaultMode ? mDefaultPlayer : mChildPlayer));
                    if (isDefaultMode) {
                        result = Games.Snapshots.open(mGoogleApiClient, mDefaultPlayer, true).await(READ_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                    } else {
                        result = Games.Snapshots.open(mGoogleApiClient, mChildPlayer, true).await(READ_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                    }
                }
                if (result == null) {
                    return GamesStatusCodes.STATUS_TIMEOUT;
                }
                int status = result.getStatus().getStatusCode();
                Snapshot snapshot = null;
                if (status == GamesStatusCodes.STATUS_OK) {
                    snapshot = result.getSnapshot();
                } else if (status == GamesStatusCodes.STATUS_SNAPSHOT_CONFLICT) {
                    // if there is a conflict - then resolve it.
                    snapshot = processSnapshotOpenResult(RC_LOAD_SNAPSHOT, result, 0);
                    // if it resolved OK, change the status to Ok
                    if (snapshot != null) {
                        status = GamesStatusCodes.STATUS_OK;
                    } else {
                        LogUtils.logD(TAG, "Conflict was not resolved automatically");
                    }
                }
                if (snapshot != null) {
                    try {
                        readSavedGame(snapshot);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        LogUtils.logE(TAG, "Error while reading snapshot contents: " + e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
                return status;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Integer status) {
                // play with your status
            }
        };

        task.execute();
```

Comment: Hi @John Steve, this might be a bit late. Can you show the whole code?

Comment: for this solution you have just put in. Can you show the whole code that uses `.await(YOUR_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS)`